# How send form with vue axios to Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

how can I send data from vue app to Symfony by axios? When I try send data Symfony request don't see them.

Controller code:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(TeacherType::class);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid()) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'code' => "400",
            'data' => $this->getErrorMessages($form),
        ]);
    }

    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'code' => 200,
    ));
```

axios:

```
      sent() {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/valid', {
         firstname: this.firstname
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

form:

```
 <form @submit.prevent="sent" id="form" name="teacher" method="POST"  action="#">
        <input type="text" name="teacher[firstname]" v-model="firstname">
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
```

Always my response is: {'code' : 400} and alert that firstname should not to be blank (in form is set assert NotBlank for firstname)

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try remove `$form->handleRequest($request);`, `handleRequest` not working with api calls

Update.

Here simple example for validating entity

Entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class SomeClass
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $content;
}
```

FormType:

```
class SomeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('content', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SomeClass::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

FormHandler:

```
class FormHandler
{
    private $formFactory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $formFactory)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }

    public function handleWithSubmit(
        array $data,
        string $type,
        $entity,
        array $options = []
    ) {
        $form = $this->formFactory->create($type, $entity, $options);
        $form->submit($data);

        return $this->processSubmitted($form, $entity);
    }

    private function processSubmitted(FormInterface $form, $entity)
    {
        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            return $form->getErrors();
        }

        if (!is_object($entity)) {
            $entity = $form->getData();
        }

        return $entity;
    }
}
```

Inject `FormHandler` in controller and call

```
$handled = $this->formHandler->handleWithSubmit($request->request->all(), SomeType::class, new SomeClass());
if (!$handled instanceof SomeClass) {
    // return errors
}
```

Comment: It's not worked. So how I should make validation form using Symfony as REST

Comment: Ok I used $validator-validate but now I don't know how parse string from $errors to js object
Object(App\Entity\Teacher).firstname: This value should not be blank. (code c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3)

Comment: Updated answer with simple example for validating entity.

Comment: `handleRequest not working with api calls` bollocks

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your fields in the HTML document are named incorrectly.

Currently:

`teacher[firstname]`

but rather should be (more or less):

`teacher_teacher[firstname]`

Use a `FormFactoryInterface` to created a named form instead:

```
public function yourAction(Request $request, FormFactoryInterface $forms)
{
    $form = $this->forms->createNamed('', TeacherType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid()) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'code' => '400',
            'data' => $this->getErrorMessages($form),
        ]);
    }

    return new JsonResponse(['code' => 200]);
}
```

When you create a form without a name (eg. `$this->createForm(TeacherType::class)`) a name is autogenerated for you: the name of the form without `Form` and `Type` words in the end, thus the need to have the `teacher_` part before the field's name.

Answer (score 0):

Install the FOS Rest bundle and make sure you are have a serializer installed. I would use the Symfony Serializer

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/1-setting_up_the_bundle.html

Basically it will make decode the HTTP request body and Accept headers which is needed for the `$form->handleRequest($request)` which will then show the form as submitted.